# SPI slave within boundary scan on STM32F4

Tags: spi, jtag

I'd like to test a SPI slave on my STM32F4 via JTAG boundary scanning methods (best would be using OpenOCD, instead of other special tool).
Does somebody know details and typical pitfalls of such thing?
What I found was [this](https://www.corelis.com/blog/spi-flash-component-programming/) site, whereas [this](https://www.corelis.com/education/tutorials/boundary-scan/) neatly explains boundary scanning.

I am thankful for any hint on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

As the linked site points out, testing your µC's output on the SPI pins through boundary scan will suffer from very low speed (because you have to feed the corresponding bit-banging commands through the boundary-scan protocol, which is far from efficient).

Using the STM32F4 controller, I therefore suggest you to keep the CPU in debug (break), and to set up the GPIOs and SPI through JTAG (as if the firmware were doing this from inside). Then, you are free to put entire data bytes/words into the TX register and poll the SPI status and RX register. This is one or two levels above the (plain) boundary scan method, but it will be quite easy to implement.

(Only) if you want to take this idea even some steps further, you can use JTAG first to switch the clock settings to higher speed or to add DMA (and write larger amounts of data to RAM before triggering the SPI transfer).